# Run before all tests

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use cy.writeFile to write my fixture files against an api. I need these fixture files to be generated before any Cypress tests run, since all the tests will use these fixture files. I only need this to be run one time, before any tests run, not before each test.

I've tried adding a before function to the /cypress/support/index.js file but it doesn't create the fixture files when I run "cypress run".

```
import './commands'

before(function() {
   // runs once before all tests in the block
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
    const fixturesPath = 'cypress/fixtures/';
    const fixtureExtension = '.json';

    let routePath = 'locations';
    cy.request(`${apiUrl}${routePath}`).then((response) => {
      cy.writeFile(`${fixturesPath}${path}${fixtureExtension}`, response.body);
    });
 });
```

Shouldn't this before hook run before any of my tests using "cypress run" run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should run before any of your tests.

The fixture is not created because the request fails. It's due to any number of reasons, for instance: the api is not ready when Cypress runs, or it requires authentication ... you'd better double-check that.

I made an example [here](https://github.com/tmhung88/typescript-starters/commit/f05464dd8a81d725fa6e93685d080417ed3cdea2). Before starting cypress **yarn cy:run**, you have to make sure both the api server (**yarn start:mock**) and webserver (**yarn start**) are ready.

---

Another note that the **before()** function in **support/index.js** is not run one time because [it's included in every test suite](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-file) so let's say you have 3 test files, then it's executed 3 times.

Comment: Thanks Hung. The fact that before() runs before every test suite is a deal breaker for me. I just need a one time hook to use cy.writeFile to hit several api endpoints and write the json files to my cypress fixtures. I then use these fixtures to stub out the xhr fed to my tests. Seems like there would be a one-time hook that runs before Cypress tests run.

Comment: For now, I've come up with this solution: using npm scripts to do what I need.

    "prebuild:e2e": "npm run start:web-server && ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/writeFixtureFilesFromApi.spec.ts'",
    "e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/server-test start:web-server http-get://localhost:4200 cypress:run-tests",

Comment: @lance-p in this case, you need a small nodeJS script that calls the api and write responses into files before starting cypress.